# What is the pythonic way to replace all occurences of a substring t of s given a list of indices where t occurs disjointly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, replace, substring

This code has a bug in it.  Given a list of indices `inds` where `old` is already known to occur (disjointly for two distinct indexes), and a `new` replacement string, what is the result string?

```
# Replace substring old with new in s at indices inds
def replace_substrings_at(self, inds, old, new):
    s = self._input
    inds = sorted(inds)
    res = s
    for i in inds:
        res = res[:inds[0]] + res[inds[0]:].replace(old, new, 1)
    return res
```

Regards.

I am aware that `str.replace()` has a count parameter.  But I don't want to replace all of the occurences, only the specific list I specify, which can be all over the place!

---

Here's a better version, but is there a simpler way?

```
# Replace substring old with new in s at indices inds known to be disjoint w.r.t. old
def replace_substrings_at(self, inds, old, new):
    s = self._input
    inds = sorted(inds)
    res = s[:inds[0]]
    for k in range(len(inds)):
        i = inds[k]
        res += new
        if k + 1 < len(inds):
            res += s[i+len(old):inds[k+1]]
    return res
```

Comment: I'd say turn the string into a list, replace the desired indices with slice assignment backwards, then rejoin into a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following splits the string up at the locations where the replacements are to occur and then joins the parts back together with the replacement. This uses the idea of ending up with `'other'.join(['hi ', ' is a this string of ', ''])`.

This code assumes that the replacement ranges are disjoint. That is no number in `inds` is less than `len(old)` from the next.

```
def replace_substrings(s, inds, old, new):
    d = len(old)
    c = 0
    l = []
    for i in sorted(inds):
        l.append(s[c:i])
        c = i+d
    l.append(s[c:])
    return new.join(l)
```

Using the same example as TigerhawkT3's answer:

```
>>> replace_substrings('hi this is a this string of this', (3, 28), 'this', 'other')
'hi other is a this string of other'
```

This costs a lot less for longer strings as it does not use `list(s)` which can result in the string taking up between 10 to 50 bytes per string byte. I don't even want to think about the quadratic copying that goes on in doing `l[i:i+d] = new` when `len(old) != len(new)`.

Answer (score 1):

As I said in a comment, turn the string into a list, replace the desired indices with slice assignment backwards, then rejoin into a string.

```
def replace_substrings(s, inds, old, new):
    l = list(s)
    d = len(old)
    new = list(new)
    for i in sorted(inds, reverse=True):
        l[i:i+d] = new
    return ''.join(l)
```

Result:

```
>>> replace_substrings('hi this is a this string of this', (3, 28), 'this', 'other')
'hi other is a this string of other'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `old` shouldn't be an argument of your function since you only need `len(old)` here. You need either `old` or `indices`+`len` but not both.

A one-liner (I took the example from TigerHawkT3 answer):

```
>>> s, inds, old, new = 'hi this is a this string of this', [3, 13, 28], 'this', 'other'
>>> new.join(s[slice(*ij)] for ij in zip([None]+[i+len(old) for i in inds], inds+[None]))
'hi other is a other string of other'
```

**Explanation.** You want to replace `s[inds[i]:inds[i]+len(old)]` by `new` in `s`, that is keep all the chunks `s[inds[i-1]+len(old):inds[i]]` and fill the gaps with `new`. That's a simple `new.join`.
How to build the chunks? `[i+len(old) for i in inds]` are the starting indices, `inds` are the end indices:

```
>>> list(zip([i+len(old) for i in inds], inds))
[(7, 3), (17, 13), (32, 28)]
```

You see that we have to shift the start indices to get the correct slices. We want:

```
[(None, 3), (7, 13), (17, 28), (32, None)]
```

(`None` means `0` for the start indice and `len(s)` for the end indice). Just insert a `None` in front of the start indices, and at the end of the end indices:

```
zip([None]+[i+len(old) for i in inds], inds+[None])
```

The rest is obvious, since `slice(*ij)` is the slice `ij[0]:ij[1]`.

It's fun but (there is a *but*) I don't think it's pythonic:

```
>>> import this
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

...
Readability counts.
...
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
...
```